# Optimal way to find derivative - numerically

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods, interpolation

Suppose we are given points $x_0,x_1,x_2$ evenly spaced points $(x_0-x_1=x_1-x_2)$, and $u(x_1),u(x_2),u(x_3)$ Where $u$ is some function.

Find the best way to approximate $u''(x)$ using only the above data, and approximate the error.

Normally, I would use the method of undetermined coefficients, but that would require that $x$ is one of the given points. This case is different. In this case, we are given 3 points and we are asked to find an approximation for the derivative at any point.

Interpolation comes to mind, but who says it is the best way?

Would appreciate any help, I'm quite new to this material.

Comment: Interpolate and then differentiate the interpolant.

Answer (score 1):

Approximate by:

$$u''(x_2)=\frac{u(x_3)-2u(x_2)+u(x_1)}{h^2}$$, where $h=x_2-x_1$

Or interpolate with Lagrange polynomial

Comment: He doesn't need the second derivative at $x_2$, he needs it at an unknown $x$. I think there is no escaping interpolation here.

Comment: One could write similar differences for the end points and then interpolate the second derivative estimates over the three points.

Comment: There is a unique polynomial interpolant of degree at most 2 passing through three points with distinct abcissae. The second derivative of such an interpolant will be constant, and the value will be equal to the one given above. So I don't know why others place seem to emphasize interpolation.